# How do you create URL paths without using directories with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to create URLs in PHP and use the path (***$path***) in **if statements**.

At work, we use ASP Classic and have some file(s) that allows us to do things like:

```
<%
 if path = "checkout" then

 <!--#include file="ViewCheckout.asp"-->

 elseif path = "billing" then

 <!--#include file="ViewBilling.asp"-->

 end if
%>
```

We can use the ' **if path = "checkout"** ' pretty much anywhere on our site. The curious thing is that '**http://myworksite.com/checkout/**' is the URL of the **checkout** page, yet there is no directory on our server called "**checkout**"... The above is just a couple of the list of '**if path = "blah"**' includes that appear in our 'start.asp' (The file that contains the base template of the pages).

I've seen files like ParseURL.asp and other files (at work) that somehow create these URLs and allow us to use them globally. I am trying to learn how this is done in PHP (At work, we run Windows Server, I have a Linux box).

**What I am trying to do is create the following URLs for their respective pages:**

- http://mysite.com/browse/ - browse.php
- http://mysite.com/contact/ - contact.php
- http://mysite.com/top100/ - top100.php

*And again, I would like to create these URLs **WITHOUT** creating directories for the paths.*

I have read up on ***http_build_url*** and ***parse_url***, but I am having a hard time determining the way to create URLs in the manner mentioned above.

**The http_build_url tutorials I've found show this:**

```
<?php
echo http_build_url("http://user@www.example.com/pub/index.php?a=b#files",
    array(
        "scheme" => "ftp",
        "host" => "ftp.example.com",
        "path" => "files/current/",
        "query" => "a=c"
    ),
    HTTP_URL_STRIP_AUTH | HTTP_URL_JOIN_PATH | HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY | HTTP_URL_STRIP_FRAGMENT
);
?>
```

The thing is, I can't figure out if this just outputs **ftp://ftp.example.com/pub/files/current/?a=b&a=c** as text or if it is a way to create a valid URL... (This is obviously an FTP address...) - PHP.net

**Note:**
At work, we can also use the **if path = "contact"** to include certain snippets like this:

```
<%
 if path = "contact" or path = "chat" or path = "checkout" then

 <div id="communication-nav">
  <ul>
   <li>Some link 1</li>
   <li>Some link 2</li>
   <li>Some link 3</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 end if
%>
```

If anyone can give me some pointers on how to re-create this using PHP, I would be very grateful!

Am I researching the right functions? Do I need to use some sort of URL Re-write function?

Comment: Can you use Apache mod_rewrite on your server?

Comment: htaccess and URL Rewrite do the work

Comment: @dpk2442 I will see if I'm able to. I haven't read up on mod_rewrite yet. Is that different than the URL rewrite Gabriel is referring to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual folders with apache mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127724/virtual-folders-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache presenting virtual subdirectories and passing parameters to PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362349/apache-presenting-virtual-subdirectories-and-passing-parameters-to-php-script)

Comment: @Gabriel Santos I just came across a page that explains what you're talking about (http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/). If you know of a better tutorial, please do share :) Thanks guys! I will post my results when I figure this out...

Comment: One could also use a dedicated php handler script in place of directories. Designate them with `ForceType` on an extension-less php script (`browse` instead of `browse.php`), and work with the virtual `PATH_INFO` from there. // Third alternative is an php script as `ErrorDocument`, but that had drawbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I figured out how to do this the way I needed to... First, I inserted some code that made the index.php file "dynamic". I placed this where the "content" of each page was going to be displayed...

```
<?
    $p = $_GET['page'];

$page = "pages/".$p.".php";

if(file_exists($page))
    include($page);
elseif($p=="")
    include 'pages/home.php';
elseif($p=="about")
    include 'pages/about.php';
elseif($p=="contact")
    include 'pages/contact.php';
elseif($p=="disclaimer")
    include 'pages/disclaimer.php';
else
    include '404.html';
?>
```

What this does is include the appropriate "content" file that I want to show depending on what page someone is trying to view. I stored my different pages in the `/pages/` directory of my site. You can change this to whatever you want to.

Next, (if you are running an APACHE server and have the mod_rewrite module running (most hosting services and APACHE boxes have this module active) we want to open (or create if none exists in your site's directory) the .htaccess file. This can be done with notepad or dreamweaver. Just name the file ".htaccess" and make sure you don't save it as a ".txt".

The .htaccess file needs to contain the following in order to achieve what I needed...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

The `^` marks the start of the string, the `(.*)` basically designates anything can be here, the `/` is the /about`/` (there is more to this), and the `$` marks the end of the string I believe.

Note the space after **$**... After the space, you state what the URL currently is (which is what the block of code at the beginning of my answer generated)... In my case it was **index.php?page=about**. The **$1** is not a PHP variable, it represents **the value of the first variable** which is **about** (or whatever the page you are viewing is).

Now I highly recommend looking up "mod_rewrite" tutorials before dipping into this. It is new to me and pretty confusing. This video was helpful to me ( http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/394-Video-Tutorial-Eliminating-Dynamic-URLs-with-Mod-Rewrite ).

Thanks everyone for the help here! As always, it's greatly appreciated! :)

**Note** Once I got this configured, my CSS was completely broken and none of my images showed up. I played around with the hrefs and got it dialed. Apparently these false "directories" impact hrefs as though they existed? Anyways, if you encounter this, don't panic :)

Comment: Yes! :) Off course you need to make a fork in your index.php, but seeing you have the files created under '/pages', then the RewriteCond prohibits the rewriterule (file exists == true). This technique is most commonly used with a controller-pattern meaning, if first fraction of url is 'users', then database table 'users' is the target etc

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition is there to make sure that CSS, JS and images etc are still accessible and will not simply rewrite to index.php

Comment: Oh i see. I will probably modify my files today and learn more on the RewriteCond and mod_rewrite. Seems like an extremely useful tool for the toolbox :)

Answer (score 1):

Try create .htaccess file in your index / document_root folder with this contents

```
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  # -- only if not a file
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # -- only if not a directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # -- never for favicon
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  # -- rewrite if all above remains true
  # -- e.g. /perma-links/this-is-it  becomes index.php?q=perma-links/this-is-it
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For compatibility setups where overriding rewrite module is not allowed or not available, then wrap the codeblock with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     #rewrite rules
</IfModule>
```

Comment: see here how the IIS works rewrite http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Will the code you provided produce URLs like mysite.com/about/ or mysite.com/inde.php?q=$1 ?

Comment: So the code that you gave me here does the opposite of what I need. If I wanted to take 'mysite.com/motocross/index.php?page=about' and convert it to 'mysite.com/motocross/about/', how would I do that? I have learned how to do many other mod_rewrites, but none show how to do the above...

Comment: I would love to see how to do this without creating a RewriteRule for each individual url by hand...

Comment: BTW, this works as well. Earlier, I misinterpreted the last line. I thought the 'index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]' was what the outcome would be, which it isn't. Thank you @mschr for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have mod_rewrite installed, try the following .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*) $1.php
```